# OpenLayers overriding point radius for all rendering intents

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In OpenLayers, I'm trying to override the point radius for all of the point style rendering intents (default, select and temporary). Currently I do this:

```
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
  "default": OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({pointRadius: radius},OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']),
  "select": OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({pointRadius: radius},OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['select']),
  "temporary": OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({pointRadius: radius},OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['temporary'])
});
```

It seems like there should be a way to just say to override point radius in all of them, but I can't figure out how to do that. I would have hoped that by default the point radius is inherited from default into select and temporary, but if I override it in just default (without overriding anything in select and temporary), they use the original default point size.

Comment: have you called `vectorLayer.redraw();` after this?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `vectorLayer.redraw();` afterward.

Comment: The problem isn't that it's redrawing, but it just seems like a lot of code to override one property for all 3 rendering intents. I'm just wondering if there's a way to simplify this code. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: I see. Well if you apply your new `styleMap` to the vector layer and redraw it, it should apply the new style for ALL of the features in that vector layer. Are you only applying it to the single feature instead of the entire layer?

Comment: It does work as I expect it do. What I'm trying to do though is basically set the pointRadius property just one time, rather than having to set it for the default, select and temporary.

Comment: I see... okay. I, doubt there is a simpler way. I think the code is fine.